# How do I redirect to an error page if Azure website down or non contactable? Traffic manager or what?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

If there is any issue with connecting to my Azure Website, then I need to automatically redirect to a polite "Issue with Website, being resolved, back soon" type page, and then hopefully when Azure issue fixed, ie site contactable again, to redirect back to original site.

What is the best way to do this? I suspect it is via some Azure feature. I have heard Traffic manager may be of use, but know little about it.

Advice would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: traffic manager will direct users to a different region.  you'll need to pay to have your website hosted in each region.

Comment: Ah, wrong thought..... Then, for the short term,  I need to have a simple redirect mechanism to a error page. How could I achieve this? Possibly in the future we may also want to redirect to another data centre, but as you say, lots more money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is two host two different instances of your website in different regions and use the Azure Traffic manager to load balance between the two regions.  That way if one region goes down for some reason your customers will be redirected to the other region automatically.

Comment: Yes , I have been thinking about this, but I am worried how one would easily keep the web site and database in sync in both regions.

Comment: Have you considered using a WebJob or looked at the new Standard or Premium Azure SQL Offerings? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/#basic-standard-and-premium

Comment: How would a webjob help me? Also, with regard to the SQL ideas, my concern is that the issue could be more general than SQL specific, as I believe was the case for this event. Having a mechanism to redirect to a page if a hang occurs occurs or an error status code such as 502 would be a great start. Question is how to do this.